# PrintWrite new CSV file after validating information from old CSV file and LOAD DATA INFILE into MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, csv, model-view-controller, netbeans

Currently working on this CSV file with lots of entries. Then I did some validation and insert the validated entries into new CSV file. Finally, I did a LOAD DATA INFILE sql query for the new CSV file, but I got 0 results in database. The LOAD DATA INFILE query is able to load the old CSV file though.

The code below calls the method

```
createNewUserCSV(validatedUsers, OUTPUT_PATH);
String csvDirectory = OUTPUT_PATH + File.separator + "newUser.csv";
String getCSVDirectory = csvDirectory.replace(File.separator, "/");
userDAO.insertUserByFile(getCSVDirectory);
```

This is my createNewUserCSV method (This code seems to work fine as I can see the newUser.csv created and is in the folder i specified.

```
private void createNewUserCSV(ArrayList<User> validatedUsers, String outputPath) {
    try{
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputPath + File.separator + "newUser.csv", true));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("name");
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("password");
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("email");
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("gender");
        sb.append('\n');

        for(User user: validatedUsers){
            sb.append(user.getName());
            sb.append(',');
            sb.append(user.getPassword());
            sb.append(',');
            sb.append(user.getEmail());
            sb.append(',');
            sb.append(user.getGender());
            sb.append('\n');
        }

        writer.write(sb.toString());
        writer.close();

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, when I tried using LOAD DATA INFILE for newUser.csv it does not work, it works for oldUser.csv though with the query.

```
 public void insertUserByFile(String csvFileDirectory) {
    //boolean success = true;
    try {
        conn = dbController.getConnection();
        //Load data infile
        query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + csvFileDirectory + "' INTO TABLE user " 
                    +"FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' " 
                    +"ENCLOSED BY '\"' " 
                    +"LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' " 
                    +"IGNORE 1 LINES";
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //success = false;
    } finally {
        if (dbController != null) {
            dbController.close(conn, pstmt, rs);
        }
    }
    //return success;
}
```

All testing was done locally

Output from MySQL upon uploading the newUser.csv

```
0 row(s) affected Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Output from MySQL upon uploading the oldUser.csv

```
21396 row(s) affected
```

Is my newUser.csv having issue? 
My newUser.csv do have the correct number of validated entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams that you are appending `\n` inside createNewUserCSV(), but you are calling LOAD DATA INFILE using `\r\n`. So replace:

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

with:

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

or append `\r\n` inside createNewUserCSV().

Also, in regards of LOAD DATA INFILE, it can be that you run into an error - maybe without actually seeing it on screen:

> ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the
>   --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

It means: The LOAD DATA INFILE has no permission to read the csv file (`newUser.csv`). Then you must set `secure-file-priv` in the configuration file of your database (my.cnf, or my.ini) yourself. Like this:

```
[mysqld]
secure-file-priv = "<PATH-TO-FOLDER-CONTAINING-THE-CSV-FILES>/"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Also note that [by default] you can only read and write files stored in sacred locations, as specified by variable *@@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv***

Ubuntu 16.04 (EASY): Find out where you are allowed to write

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;
+---------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv |
+---------------------------+
| /var/lib/mysql-files/     |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then, just write there

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM train INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/test.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
Query OK, 992931 rows affected (1.65 sec)

mysql>
```